# Usage of SGDClassifier on MNIST

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, mnist

I am performing a self-study with the **Hands-On Machine Learning w/ scikit_Learn" (*O'Reilly*)** and currently using the MNIST data with different classifiers.

The text at page 94 says that `SGDClassifier` is able to perform a multi-class classification and uses an OvA algorithm. When I try to fit the classifier like so:

```
sgd_clf = SGDClassifier()
sgd_clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I receive an error:

> bad input shape (55000, 10).

This seems to contradict the text.

---

#### Data information

`x_train.shape` is 55000x784 and `y_train.shape` is 55000x10 and they are both `numpy.ndarray`.

When I fit the `KNeighborsClassifier` it works perfectly.

Does `SGDClassifier` solve the multi-class classification problem?

Thanks!

Comment: did you looke here? https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/03_classification.ipynb

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I couldn't download the data as outlined in the book (mldata server offline) so I was using the MNIST data set from tensorflow and didn't realize the data format was different. I changed to the sklearn data set and made the appropriate changes and it is now working.

Comment: Since the MNIST data is a mulit-class problem, I would advise you to directly pass the original `y` values (class names probably) to the `fit()`. Scikit-learn mostly automatically handles strings in `y`. A 2-d vector of y (often called indicator matrix) is only useful when handling multi-label classification.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#sgd),

> As other classifiers, SGD has to be fitted with two arrays: an array X
>   of size [n_samples, n_features] holding the training samples, and an
>   array Y of size [n_samples] holding the target values (class labels)
>   for the training samples

This means that `y` is a 1D array that consists of class labels, like in the following example (taken from the link above):

```
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
>>> X = [[0., 0.], [1., 1.]]
>>> y = [0, 1]
>>> clf = SGDClassifier(loss="hinge", penalty="l2")
>>> clf.fit(X, y)
SGDClassifier(alpha=0.0001, average=False, class_weight=None, epsilon=0.1,
       eta0=0.0, fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15,
       learning_rate='optimal', loss='hinge', n_iter=5, n_jobs=1,
       penalty='l2', power_t=0.5, random_state=None, shuffle=True,
       verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

Hence, you should transform your `y` into a vector that consists of class labels (0-9 in your case).